# call the function response in another function in Django RestFramework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I tried calling the another function inside the function which will return the response.I have tried this approach but couldn't able to achieve it.

I'm just getting error as

```
AssertionError at /api/Data/CurrentRunningActivity2/54
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

views.py:

```
  @api_view(['GET'])
def CurrentRunningActivityView2(request, UserID):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        CurrentRunningActivity(UserID)


def CurrentRunningActivity(UserID):
    
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetCurrentRunningActivity] @UserId=%s',(UserID,))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
    
     
        for row in result_set:

                TaskId=row[0]
                Number=row[1]
                Opened=row[2]
                Contacttype=row[3]
                Category1=row[4]
                State=row[5]
                Assignmentgroup=row[6]
                CountryLocation=row[7]
                Openedfor=row[8]
                Employeenumber=row[9]
                Shortdescription=row[10]
                Internaldescription=row[11]
                Additionalcomments=row[12]
                TaskName = row[1]
                print("Number", Number)

                return Response({ "TaskId": TaskId, "Number":Number,"Opened":Opened, "Contacttype":Contacttype,
         "Category1":Category1, "State":State, "Assignmentgroup":Assignmentgroup, "CountryLocation":CountryLocation,
         "Openedfor":Openedfor, "Employeenumber":Employeenumber , "Shortdescription":Shortdescription,
         "Internaldescription":Internaldescription, "Additionalcomments":Additionalcomments,"TaskName":TaskName},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put return statement in the CurrentRunningActivityView2 to return the Response from  CurrentRunningActivity. Otherwise it won't return the Response from the second function.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def CurrentRunningActivityView2(request, UserID):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return CurrentRunningActivity(UserID)
```

Comment: Thanks I have added, But I'm getting another error as "AssertionError at /api/Data/CurrentRunningActivity2/54
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`"

Comment: You are put the return statement inside the loop (for row in result_set:) , result_set may not have data to iterate?

Comment: {"TaskId":2145,"Number":"H10","Opened":"2021-04-28T18:50:42","Contacttype":"Web","Category1":"  Referral Inquiry","State":"Draft","Assignmentgroup":"IND","CountryLocation":"India","Openedfor":"ashwini.mukesh.vike","Employeenumber":11637618,"Shortdescription":"Candidate has already activated her profile however, again asking to resubmit","Internaldescription":"","Additionalcomments":"","TaskName":"H10"} This response which I get from the return response  I want to return this kind of response outside the loop